# tailwind 3 color palette not generated properly

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-mix, tailwind-3

I have worked on this for about 3 hours and cannot get a heads up on it.  I am using laravel 9.  and laravel mix.  I have followed the instructions fo upgrade tailwind shown on [the TailWind Website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide).  Yet the color pallete is not installing completely.  For example, after compiling and creating css file in the public/css/app.css, there is only one entry for the 'bg-sky' color in the app.css:

```
.bg-sky-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(56 189 248 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

There should be entries for 50,and 100 thru 900, but only 400 is offered.

btw, the gray color has all the proper gradients in the app.css, ranging from 50, 100 thru 900.

My tailwind.config.js file is as follows:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: [
      './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
      './storage/framework/views/*.php',
      './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
  ],
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            gray: colors.neutral,
        },
        fontFamily: {
            /*sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],*/
        },
        maxWidth: {
            '8xl': '88rem',
            '9xl': '96rem',
            '10xl': '104rem'
        }
    },
      fontSize: {
          'xss': '.70rem',
          'xs': '.75rem',
          'sm': '.875rem',
          'tiny': '.875rem',
          'base': '1rem',
          'lg': '1.125rem',
          'xl': '1.25rem',
          '2xl': '1.5rem',
          '3xl': '1.875rem',
          '4xl': '2.25rem',
          '5xl': '3rem',
          '6xl': '4rem',
          '7xl': '5rem',
      }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

The following is stumping me.  If I change the color gray in the tailwind.config.js like so:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            gray: colors.sky,
        },
```

Notice in the first example the setting was gray: colors.neutral.

If I go back into my generated app.css after runing laravel mix's

```
sail npm run dev
```

I still find that the color gray has been generated as expected, and has all the gradients (50, 100 - 900).  And gray is rendering as the sky color should be rendering

In other words, I can get the palette if I re-define the color gray to be colors.sky in the tailwind.config.js file.

HOWEVER, if i try to create a color this way:

```
extend: {
        colors: {
            dogcat: colors.sky,
        },
```

there is no color 'dogcat' in the generated app.css.

What Gives!  If anyone knows, would appreciate you chiming in.

Oh, and by the way, I tried adding in the colors this way into the tailwind.config.js:

```
   theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
            gray: colors.neutral,
                slate: {
    50: '#f8fafc',
    100: '#f1f5f9',
    200: '#e2e8f0',
    300: '#cbd5e1',
    400: '#94a3b8',
    500: '#64748b',
    600: '#475569',
    700: '#334155',
    800: '#1e293b',
    900: '#0f172a',
},
gray: {
    50: '#f9fafb',
    100: '#f3f4f6',
    200: '#e5e7eb',
    300: '#d1d5db',
    400: '#9ca3af',
    500: '#6b7280',
    600: '#4b5563',
    700: '#374151',
    800: '#1f2937',
    900: '#111827',
},
zinc: {
    50: '#fafafa',
    100: '#f4f4f5',
    200: '#e4e4e7',
    300: '#d4d4d8',
    400: '#a1a1aa',
    500: '#71717a',
    600: '#52525b',
    700: '#3f3f46',
    800: '#27272a',
    900: '#18181b',
},
neutral: {
    50: '#fafafa',
    100: '#f5f5f5',
    200: '#e5e5e5',
    300: '#d4d4d4',
    400: '#a3a3a3',
    500: '#737373',
    600: '#525252',
    700: '#404040',
    800: '#262626',
    900: '#171717',
},
stone: {
    50: '#fafaf9',
    100: '#f5f5f4',
    200: '#e7e5e4',
    300: '#d6d3d1',
    400: '#a8a29e',
    500: '#78716c',
    600: '#57534e',
    700: '#44403c',
    800: '#292524',
    900: '#1c1917',
},
red: {
    50: '#fef2f2',
    100: '#fee2e2',
    200: '#fecaca',
    300: '#fca5a5',
    400: '#f87171',
    500: '#ef4444',
    600: '#dc2626',
    700: '#b91c1c',
    800: '#991b1b',
    900: '#7f1d1d',
},
orange: {
    50: '#fff7ed',
    100: '#ffedd5',
    200: '#fed7aa',
    300: '#fdba74',
    400: '#fb923c',
    500: '#f97316',
    600: '#ea580c',
    700: '#c2410c',
    800: '#9a3412',
    900: '#7c2d12',
},
amber: {
    50: '#fffbeb',
    100: '#fef3c7',
    200: '#fde68a',
    300: '#fcd34d',
    400: '#fbbf24',
    500: '#f59e0b',
    600: '#d97706',
    700: '#b45309',
    800: '#92400e',
    900: '#78350f',
},
yellow: {
    50: '#fefce8',
    100: '#fef9c3',
    200: '#fef08a',
    300: '#fde047',
    400: '#facc15',
    500: '#eab308',
    600: '#ca8a04',
    700: '#a16207',
    800: '#854d0e',
    900: '#713f12',
},
lime: {
    50: '#f7fee7',
    100: '#ecfccb',
    200: '#d9f99d',
    300: '#bef264',
    400: '#a3e635',
    500: '#84cc16',
    600: '#65a30d',
    700: '#4d7c0f',
    800: '#3f6212',
    900: '#365314',
},
green: {
    50: '#f0fdf4',
    100: '#dcfce7',
    200: '#bbf7d0',
    300: '#86efac',
    400: '#4ade80',
    500: '#22c55e',
    600: '#16a34a',
    700: '#15803d',
    800: '#166534',
    900: '#14532d',
},
emerald: {
    50: '#ecfdf5',
    100: '#d1fae5',
    200: '#a7f3d0',
    300: '#6ee7b7',
    400: '#34d399',
    500: '#10b981',
    600: '#059669',
    700: '#047857',
    800: '#065f46',
    900: '#064e3b',
},
teal: {
    50: '#f0fdfa',
    100: '#ccfbf1',
    200: '#99f6e4',
    300: '#5eead4',
    400: '#2dd4bf',
    500: '#14b8a6',
    600: '#0d9488',
    700: '#0f766e',
    800: '#115e59',
    900: '#134e4a',
},
cyan: {
    50: '#ecfeff',
    100: '#cffafe',
    200: '#a5f3fc',
    300: '#67e8f9',
    400: '#22d3ee',
    500: '#06b6d4',
    600: '#0891b2',
    700: '#0e7490',
    800: '#155e75',
    900: '#164e63',
},
sky: {
    50: '#f0f9ff',
    100: '#e0f2fe',
    200: '#bae6fd',
    300: '#7dd3fc',
    400: '#38bdf8',
    500: '#0ea5e9',
    600: '#0284c7',
    700: '#0369a1',
    800: '#075985',
    900: '#0c4a6e',
},
blue: {
    50: '#eff6ff',
    100: '#dbeafe',
    200: '#bfdbfe',
    300: '#93c5fd',
    400: '#60a5fa',
    500: '#3b82f6',
    600: '#2563eb',
    700: '#1d4ed8',
    800: '#1e40af',
    900: '#1e3a8a',
},
indigo: {
    50: '#eef2ff',
    100: '#e0e7ff',
    200: '#c7d2fe',
    300: '#a5b4fc',
    400: '#818cf8',
    500: '#6366f1',
    600: '#4f46e5',
    700: '#4338ca',
    800: '#3730a3',
    900: '#312e81',
},
violet: {
    50: '#f5f3ff',
    100: '#ede9fe',
    200: '#ddd6fe',
    300: '#c4b5fd',
    400: '#a78bfa',
    500: '#8b5cf6',
    600: '#7c3aed',
    700: '#6d28d9',
    800: '#5b21b6',
    900: '#4c1d95',
},
purple: {
    50: '#faf5ff',
    100: '#f3e8ff',
    200: '#e9d5ff',
    300: '#d8b4fe',
    400: '#c084fc',
    500: '#a855f7',
    600: '#9333ea',
    700: '#7e22ce',
    800: '#6b21a8',
    900: '#581c87',
},
fuchsia: {
    50: '#fdf4ff',
    100: '#fae8ff',
    200: '#f5d0fe',
    300: '#f0abfc',
    400: '#e879f9',
    500: '#d946ef',
    600: '#c026d3',
    700: '#a21caf',
    800: '#86198f',
    900: '#701a75',
},
pink: {
    50: '#fdf2f8',
    100: '#fce7f3',
    200: '#fbcfe8',
    300: '#f9a8d4',
    400: '#f472b6',
    500: '#ec4899',
    600: '#db2777',
    700: '#be185d',
    800: '#9d174d',
    900: '#831843',
},
rose: {
    50: '#fff1f2',
    100: '#ffe4e6',
    200: '#fecdd3',
    300: '#fda4af',
    400: '#fb7185',
    500: '#f43f5e',
    600: '#e11d48',
    700: '#be123c',
    800: '#9f1239',
    900: '#881337',
}

        },
```

I added all the colors in the above way.  I got the color codes from the tailwind website.  that didn't seem to work.

I also took the color section completely out of the tailwind.config.js as well:

```
 theme: {
    extend: {

        fontFamily: {
            /*sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],*/
        },
        maxWidth: {
            '8xl': '88rem',
            '9xl': '96rem',
            '10xl': '104rem'
        }
    },
```

Still no success.  However, bg-sky- shows up twice in the generated app.css file:

```
.bg-sky-300 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(125 211 252 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.bg-sky-400 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(56 189 248 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

In fact the term '-sky-' appears only twice in the entire app.css file.

It seems that the only color that has been generated properly is gray, as it shows up 61 times in the generated css file.  here ae the numbers

```
-blue-          => 15 times
-indigo-        => 31 times
-slate-         => 0 times
-gray-         => 61 times
-rose-         => 1 time
-zinc-         => 0 times
-stone-       => 0 times
-red-          => 15 times
-violet-       => 0 times
-pink-        => 6 times
-lime-        => 0 times
-green-     => 9 times
-emerald-  => 0 times
-teal-        => 0 times
-cyan-       => 0 times
-sky-       => 2 times
-neutral-   => 0 times
-orange-   => 0 times
-purple-   => 4 times
-fuchsia-   => 0 times
-yellow-   => 3 times
-amber-    => 0 times
```

What gives!

Comment: obviously the colors need to be referenced by your _content_ in order to be in the css file.  You have places where these colors are specified?

Comment: that was not obvious to me.  I was under the impression that if you were in dev mode, tailwind would make the entire pallete available. If I understand you, you are saying that npm run dev will not bring in the color orange-500 unless you have ref'd it somewhere in the content.  That seems backward.  That means to test colors you have to ref it in a class attribute, then run npm run dev, then if you don't like what you chose then you have to choose another color / gradient and run npm run dev.

Comment: Is that what you are saying?  Is there there anyway to have the whole thing load until you tell it not to load everything, only what you are using?

Comment: thank you for the tip.  I wish i had asked stackoverflow earlier today!  Damn.  So from here on in, i will run npm run watch so i don't have to run dev all the time.  Again thank you for your comment Snapey.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think Snapey's comment triggered the answer.  using laravel mix, i didn't realize that it would not load the entire tailwind framework.  I thought it would wile I was using npm run dev.  But, I have to make reference to the attreibute setting before laravel mix will place it in the public css file.

So, I will run npm run watch so it will auto generate the css file as I add the attribute settings.

### If someone knows how to install the entire tailwind framework under laravel mix while in development, would appreciate the comment.

Okay, but here is a follow-on situation that this behavior is causing problems for me.  I am trying to build a site where the end user will be able to easily change colors, etc.  To do that I am using livewire to set values to public variables in the livewire controller.  But when I run npm run watch, the process compiles the css file before the variables are assigned the values in the blade template.  So if I set a variable public $bgcolor = "bg-yellow-100" because that is the color the user chose on setup, the laravel mix does not pick up the chosen color.

I suppose the answer is to load all the colors and gradients that I want available to the user into a blade file that I never call in the live site.  That way the user will be able to see the changes they want to make.

Comment: The JIT mode was introduced so that purging classes what not required. Yes, it is useless unless you are watching for changes and regenerating the CSS.  It is done in this way because the large number of classes created by tailwind causes some browser performance issues.

Comment: The benefits of JIT explained here by Adam himself https://youtu.be/3O_3X7InOw8